# Access Windows shortcuts (.lnk) data on Node

Tags: node.js, windows

Is there any way I can parse shortcut data from .lnk files in Node (for instance, and mainly, the path it's pointing at)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the npm package `windows-shortcuts`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-shortcuts

Example:

```
ws.query("C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Windows Update.lnk", 
console.log);

/* From console:
null { expanded:
   { args: 'startmenu',
     workingDir: 'C:\\Windows\\system32',
     icon: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\wucltux.dll' },
  target: '%windir%\\system32\\wuapp.exe',
  args: 'startmenu',
  workingDir: '%windir%\\system32',
  runStyle: 1,
  icon: '%windir%\\system32\\wucltux.dll',
  iconIndex: '0',
  hotkey: 0,
  desc: 'Delivers software updates and drivers, and provides automatic updating options.' }
*/
```

Comment: Unfortunately this library doesn't work in electron projects and shows no signs of being fixed: https://github.com/j201/windows-shortcuts/issues/9

Comment: 1. not working with non-ascii chars
2. very slow because spawns separate process instead of reading lnks with fs module

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org), it has a built-in method:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellreadshortcutlinkshortcutpath-windows

```
import { shell } from 'electron';

const parsed = shell.readShortcutLink(shortcutPath);
```

- `target` *String* - The target to launch from this shortcut.
- `cwd` *String* (optional) - The working directory. Default is empty.
- `args` *String* (optional) - The arguments to be applied to target when launching from this shortcut. Default is empty.
- `description` *String* (optional) - The description of the shortcut. Default is empty.
- `icon` *String* (optional) - The path to the icon, can be a DLL or EXE. icon and iconIndex have to be set together. Default is empty, which uses the target's icon.
- `iconIndex` *Number* (optional) - The resource ID of icon when icon is a DLL or EXE. Default is 0.
- `appUserModelId` *String* (optional) - The Application User Model ID. Default is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Aminadav Glickshtein's answer didn't work for me since the package involved has a problem in electron projects, as per my comment. The following package worked better:

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-shortcuts-ps

Comment: I found this windows-shortcuts-ps to work very well, within Electron (9), where none of the above would. 

It exports a function and returns a Promise, so you use it actually this way:

```
const { getPath } = require('windows-shortcuts-ps')

const   truefilePath = await getPath(lnkFilePath)
```