# Node JS resolve paths with symlinks

Tags: node.js, fs

I am retrieving a list of items in a directory with `fs.readdirSync(somePath)`. In this directory there are subdirectories or links to other directories.

```
/somePath/
  - P13
  - P31.lnk
  - P46
  - someOther.file
```

In each of the product folders there is a `config.xml` which I need to retrieve. I have filtered/mapped the list to either get `['P13', 'P31.lnk', 'P46']` or  `['P13', 'P31', 'P46']`. I need the real path to every config file (to read it with `fs.readFileSync`).

For P13 and P46 this is easy, but I'm struggling with P13. I tried several things with `fs.realpathSync()`:

- `fs.realpathSync('/someDir/P13/config.xml')`
- `fs.realpathSync('/someDir/P13.lnk')`
- `fs.realpathSync('/someDir/P13')`

Which all yield either an error or just the path of the link file, but don't follow the link. Is there any way in JS/Node to follow these links through? I need to do this on Windows, if this makes a difference.

Cheers and thanks

Comment: If I got your question correctly, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896873/how-to-read-a-symlink-in-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Windows shortcuts (.lnk) data on Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610502/access-windows-shortcuts-lnk-data-on-node)

Comment: @Mehdi thanks for the link, sadly this one doesn't work in electron and is not maintained.

Comment: @mamounothman thanks, didn't find that one, tried it but trying to do `fs.readlinkSync('/someDir/P13.lnk')` just throws `Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink`.

Comment: @Tom not sure how this work on windows, maybe you have to provide absolute path.

Comment: @mamounothman Absolute paths did not work. But I got to talk to someone who's got more expertise in windows than me and informed me that the `.lnk` files are not real links, just something the windows GUI creates. You can create real symlinks or junction point with the shell (not with the explorer) and it should work with those. Will try it this afternoon.